# Unable to use GET method in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a `web API` in which `CRUD` operations are performed. Now I wanted to test it on real time basis, so I decided to make a console application by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) tutorial. The tutorial provides the code in which while running the application the code its self created a product and get, update and delete it. But I want to use user input. I am successful in creating product(s). But while getting it i am facing an issue, see my code

**Class**

```
class Product
{           

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Console**

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();



    static void ShowProduct(Product product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Name}\tPrice: {product.Price}\tCategory: {product.Category}");
    }

    static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/product/", product);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }

    static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        Product product = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        }
        return product;
    }

static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        int a;
        decimal price = 0;
        string name = null, category = null;
        char option;

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7361/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            label:
            Console.Write("1. Create a product\n");
            Console.Write("2. View products\n");
            Console.Write("3. Update a product\n");
            Console.Write("4. Delete a product\n");
            Console.Write("5. Exit\n");

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your choice: ");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            switch(a)
            {
                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter name of the product: ");
                    name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter price of the product: ");
                    price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter category of the product: ");
                    category = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    // Create a new product
                    Product product = new Product { Name = name, Price = price, Category = category };

                    var url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");

                    Console.WriteLine("Want to create more product(s)? (y/n): ");
                    option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    if(option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        goto case 1;
                    }
                    else if(option == 'n' || option == 'N')
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        goto label;
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:

                    // Get the product

                    product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                    ShowProduct(product);

                    break;

                   //case 3:...
                   //case 4:...

                case 5:

                    Environment.Exit(0);

                    break;
            }
}
```

In `case 2` at `product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);`, I am unable to use `url` variable as it says `Use of unassigned local variable 'url'`.

Also I can't declare `var` outside it because it will be not initialized to anyone.

I have tried to change the type from `var` to `string` but still unable to perform the task.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you started your console application and immediately chose option 2? Where would it get the product from?

Comment: You have a simple scoping issue, nothing to do with making web requests. Your code would be cleaner and easier to reason about if it were a while loop instead of switches with `goto`s.

Comment: @KirkLarkin when I choose option 2 then nothing happens and after pressing the enter button the application exits

Comment: @Crowcoder I had to make user option so that's why I use switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share your tips on how to bribe the compiler to allow use of unassigned variable ;)

You're trying to use variable `url` within `case 2:` although that variable *doesn't* exist within the scope of this case. It seems you have declared `url` within `case 1:` and technically this variable can't be access past the `break` statement closing case 1.

Go back a step and have a quick read on [variable scope within switch statement in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

A quick fix is to delcare `Uri url` just before the `switch()`, so it's accessible inside all of the cases in the switch. Just make sure you either give it an initial value or add a `default:` statement and initialize it there before using it further down in the code.

Comment: I have declared `Uri url` outside the switch. And after running the application when I choose `option 2` I get this error `No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Product' from content with media type 'text/html'.3`